# Run JS script containing load() and print() functions in Debian

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rhino

I need to run a map-reduce JS script in Debian: the script reads from and writes to a MongoDB instance running locally (mongod) and creates a table of similar entries.
The problem is that the script contains **load** and **print** functions:

```
load("map-reduce-.../somefile.js");


var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
...

var db = new Db('results', new Server('localhost', 27017));
// Connect to db
...

var collectionName = "labelgroups"; //collection to store last executions
var testset = "testset"; //collection target of map-reduce
var mapReduceName = "timedmapReduce"; //output collection

var collection = db.getCollection(collectionName);
if (collection.exists() == null) {
    // Create collection
    print("mapReduce collection is being created");
    db.createCollection(collectionName);
    collection = db.getCollection(collectionName);
    collection.insert({ ... });
} else { ... }
```

I tried using NodeJS but I failed installing the modules for those functions. I also tried to run it using Rhino, which handles print and load functions but I can't manage to get a MongoDB module working on it.
How can I run this script in Debian?

Answer (score 0):

Use [console.log()](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data) for this.

Example:

```
console.log('This line will be written to stdout');
```